# HangFire Dashboard on Hosted Blazor App not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, hangfire

I am migrating an MVC app to hosted blazor and the routing setup seems to skip the HangFire Dashboard. It always falls back to the Blazor app and renders 404 since the /hangfire route does not exist.

I have tried

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

and

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();
}
```

but it seems not to work.
Same applies to HealthChecksUI. Did you get it serving on a hosted blazor app?

Comment: Did you add `services.AddHangfireServer();`?

Comment: yes, `services.AddHangfire(...)` and `services.AddHangfireServer(...)`

Comment: Can you post your entire startup?

Comment: unfortunately not. ill create a demo repo and post a link

Comment: I have the same issue. @MariusSteinbach Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to fix Blazor's routing - but there is a workaround: Make a razor page containing a hangfire iframe:

```
@page "/HangfireContainer"

<iframe src="@("hangfire")"></iframe>

@code {
}
```